# Google Sheets- Countif Formula Count Cells specific text Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a google sheet in which I count values in Column L against a reference sheet 'Ref' and then against a status Column W

```
IF(AND(COUNTIF(Ref!$A$1:$A$100,L2),W2 <>"Cancelled",W2 <>"Postponed",W2 <> "Dropped"),"Y", "N")
```

However the values have now changed in Column L. Instead of defined values in each cell they will be a string of values in each cell, the permutations will be too great to enter into my reference sheet.

How do I still count the values in column L to correctly return a 'Y' or 'N'

I have tried

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(L2,{"*LEE*","*LON*","*LAM*"}),W2 <>"Cancelled",W2 <>"Postponed",W2 <> "Dropped"),"Y", "N")

=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Ref!$A$1:$A$100,"*"&L2&"*"),W2 <>"Cancelled",W2 <>"Postponed",W2 <> "Dropped"),"Y", "N")

=IF(AND(COUNTIF(L2,{"*LEE*","*LON*","*LAM*"}),W2 <>"Cancelled",W2 <>"Postponed",W2 <> "Dropped"),"Y", "N")
```

The values I which need to count will feature one of the following phrases 'LEE', 'LON','LAM'.

The new values that are entered into column L will look like the following

```
<Area1: Y - LEE>,<Area2: Y - MIL>
<Area3: WF>,<Area4: Y - MUN>
<Area1: YY - MUN>,<Area2: YY - LON>,<Area3: YY-LAM>
```

So I need to be able to search within the cell for 1 of the 3 phrases.

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet, with permissions set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." As it stands, the volunteer contributors here would need to manually enter data into their own sheet before they could even begin, which is a large deterrent. Help us help you

Comment: Agree with @Broly through and through.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that might work, using `arrayformula()` in a single cell.

If I've understood correctly, it looks like you're checking Col L to see if cells contain LEE LON or LAM. You're also checking to see that they appear in `Ref!$A$1:$A$100`.

On your sheet that contains col F and Col W (Status), try this in row 1 (I've used `AB1`):

```
=arrayformula({"Check";if(if(L2:L<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(flatten(query(transpose({if(regexmatch(split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"LAM|LEE|LON"),split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"|")}),"",9^9)),"\ ",""),"(\|)+","\|"),"^\||\|$",),)<>"",if(REGEXMATCH(join(" ",Ref!A2:A),if(L2:L<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(flatten(query(transpose({if(regexmatch(split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"LAM|LEE|LON"),split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"|")}),"",9^9)),"\ ",""),"(\|)+","\|"),"^\||\|$",),)),if(regexmatch(W2:W,"Cancelled|Postponed|Dropped"),"N","Y"),),)})
```

[image]

To show the working, I've got three helper columns, `AD`, `AE` and `AF`:

[image]

`AD1` gets LAM LEE or LON from col L:

```
=arrayformula({"LAM|LEE|LON entry";if(L2:L<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(flatten(query(transpose({if(regexmatch(split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"LAM|LEE|LON"),split(regexreplace(L2:L,"[^A-Z]",char(9999)),char(9999)),"|")}),"",9^9)),"\ ",""),"(\|)+","\|"),"^\||\|$",),)})
```

`AE1` checks the values in col AD to see if they appear in `Ref!A2:A`:

```
=arrayformula({"LAM|LEE|LON match";if(AD2:AD<>"",REGEXMATCH(join(" ",Ref!A2:A),AD2:AD),)})
```

`AF1` checks if the value in col AE is true, then the status from col W:

```
=arrayformula({"Check";if(AE2:AE=true,if(regexmatch(W2:W,"Cancelled|Postponed|Dropped"),"N","Y"),)})
```

The 3 helper columns are combined in `AB1`.